# More generic copy method (case class with extends)

Tags: scala, generics, traits, case-class

I have the following sealed trait:

```
sealed trait Move extends AbstractCommand {
  def execute(): Option[State] = {
      this match {
        case MoveLeft(state) => shiftCursorCharacter(-1, state)
        case MoveRight(state) => shiftCursorCharacter(1, state)
        case MoveUp(state) => shiftCursorLine(-1, state)
        case MoveDown(state) => shiftCursorLine(1, state)
      }
  }

  def copy(newState: State): Move = {
    this match {
      case MoveLeft(_) => MoveLeft(newState)
      case MoveRight(_) => MoveRight(newState)
      case MoveRightAndPast(_) => MoveRightAndPast(newState)
      case MoveUp(_) => MoveUp(newState)
    }
  }


case class MoveLeft(state: State) extends Move
case class MoveRight (state: State) extends Move
case class MoveRightAndPast (state: State) extends Move
case class MoveDown (state: State) extends Move
case class MoveUp (state: State) extends Move
```

And `AbstractCommand` looks like this:

```
abstract trait AbstractCommand {
  val state: State
  def execute(): Option[State]
}
```

Of course, I have other types of commands (extending `AbstractCommand`) that also have state and and the `execute` def. I'm quite new to Scala. I'm not able to use the built-in copy method for case classes (don't really understand why). I was wondering if there is a

**A)** better (more generic) way to write the copy method, seen as though if I add new Move commands, they all have identical copy-behaviour: I want to change the state but keep the command type, or

**B)** there is a better design to incorporate this idea (I've tried, but haven't succeeded in finding alternatives).

Comment: This is a common common example to use Scalaz/Cats State Monad. Take a look at the docs : https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/state.html and check if this is what you are looking for

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44 I'm not really 'allowed' to use external libraries ;)

Comment: Reflection maybe? `getClass.getConstructors.head.newInstance(newState).asInstanceOf[Move]`
As for `execute`, I would rather have each state implement it (or, perhaps, just have the number (`1/-1`) as a member), rather than the `match` statement in superclass

Comment: What leads you to believe that you can't use the built in `copy` for case classes? `move.copy(state = newState)` should work in-and-of itself unless you need additional functionality as part of the copy (in which case I wouldn't override the copy command but create a function which calls copy and does the additional work).

Comment: It just says 'Cannot resolve method copy' whenever I try to call it..